# updating boost libraries for Rad Studio

Tags: c++, boost, c++builder, rad

I need to update boost libraries to version 1_46, currently Rad Studio XE/2010 have 1_39 version. When I try just to overwrite boost include path compile fails with various errors from Borland VCL. When i try to add new boost libs in other path keep previous version it also fails with compile condition errors when constructing std::* classes.
I need shared_memory_manager support that is available only in new boost versions. Is there any other ways to upgrade boost libraries or use shared memory that will be available to same processes?

Compilation errors when compiling with new boost version only:

> [BCC32 Error] bad_weak_ptr.hpp(44): E2113 Virtual function 'bad_weak_ptr::what() const throw()' conflicts with base class 'std::exception'
>
> [BCC32 Error] xlocale(953): E2228 Too many error or warning messages

Comment: Post the compiliation errors.

Answer (score 2):

There are dozens of locations inside of boost which check the compiler version in order to determine whether or not certain workarounds are needed. (checking against both __CODEGEARC__ and __BORLANDC__) You need to test each of these and update the version number as appropriate. Also there are a number of defines set inside the config/compiler/codegear.hpp file (typically BOOST_HAS_* and BOOST_NO_*) which you also need to turn on/off for different versions of the compiler.

It is a very tricky and time consuming process.