# how to upgrade c++ builder 2010 boost libs

Tags: c++, boost, c++builder

As far as I know ERS C++ Builder 2010 comes with Boost libraries. During installation it will also install Boost libraries.
As new libraries will be realeased or  modified(optimized), it gets me to upgrade to the latest version. 
So i'm asking can i do this by replacing boost directory?

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as updating the $(CG_BOOST_ROOT) directory with a new boost.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304986/updating-boost-libraries-for-rad-studio/5507562#5507562) previously asked on SO.

Someone could put the effort in, and it could be possible to run many of the latest boost libraries with bcc. (and hopefully submit those changes back to boost) That hasn't really happened yet.

However, even with a Herculean effort there are some constructs used by boost that bcc just doesn't handle yet, so there will be some boost libraries that won't be usable by bcc.